# ODRefreshControl isn´t working anymore

Tags: ios, ios7, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

i tested my App on iOS 7 and recognize that my "Pull to Refresh" (ODRefreshControl https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) doesn´t work anymore.

I have to pull the scrollview extremly far down to see a small part of the spinner and the arrow icon. What could be the Problem. On iOS 5 and iOS 6 it works perfectley!!

Comment: Hey, came across the same issue not long ago. Looking through the implementation I just noticed the frame property was calculated manually. So it was actually a 4-inch display issue in my case and I fixed it with y-adjustment.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, i solved the Problem at a similar way. The Problem in my case was the Status and the Navi Bar in iOS 7. I also changed the y-adjustment :)

Comment: do you have a sample code that shows where you fixed it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added only one Value in **ODRefreshControl.m** to fix the Issue for iOS7. Maybe the value is a little bit different from app to app!

**BEFORE:**

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentInset"]) 
{
    if (!_ignoreInset) 
{
        self.originalContentInset = [[change objectForKey:@"new"] UIEdgeInsetsValue];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, -(kTotalViewHeight + self.scrollView.contentInset.top), self.scrollView.frame.size.width, kTotalViewHeight);
    }
    return;
}
```

**AFTER:**

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:     (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

NSInteger iOS7Value = 60.0f;

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentInset"]) 
{
    if (!_ignoreInset) 
{
        self.originalContentInset = [[change objectForKey:@"new"] UIEdgeInsetsValue];

        if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{

        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, -(kTotalViewHeight + self.scrollView.contentInset.top) + iOS7Value, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, kTotalViewHeight);

        } else {

            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, -(kTotalViewHeight + self.scrollView.contentInset.top), self.scrollView.frame.size.width, kTotalViewHeight);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```